# Sample a row from a subset of columns

Tags: python, pandas

Why is this throwing an error?

What is the real code I should type out?

I want to filter the dataframe by 2 column and then select a random row from that subset.

Code:

```
print(df_concepts.columns)
print(df_concepts[['id']['concept_code']].sample())
```

Traceback:

```
Index(['id', 'vocabulary_id', 'concept_code', 'concept_text'], dtype='object')
print(df_concepts[['id']['concept_code']].sample())
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Sorry if it is dead obvious

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change nested lists first and then specify number of rows:

```
print(df_concepts[['id', 'concept_code']].sample(1))
```

Comment: This is probably it. Running it now. Simple syntax error on my part. What an oversight haha